# Reading a specific part of .txt-file on given input

Tags: java

I'm developing a game where you have multiple levels and each level contains a question, an answer and some info abut the question. All this information is stored in .txt-file as shown below. What I need to do is read only a specific part of the .txt-file and the specific part is depending on the input. The input could be "question1" and then the method should return "What's 5+5? 1".

My current implementation works, but I wonder if there is a better way to do it?

Code:

```
private boolean q11 = false;
private boolean a11 = false;
private boolean i11 = false;
private boolean q12 = false;
private boolean a12 = false;
private boolean i12 = false;
private boolean q13 = false;
private boolean a13 = false;
private boolean i13 = false;
private boolean q14 = false;
private boolean a14 = false;
private boolean i14 = false;
private boolean q21 = false;
private boolean a21 = false;
private boolean i21 = false;
private boolean q22 = false;
private boolean a22 = false;
private boolean i22 = false;
private boolean q23 = false;
private boolean a23 = false;
private boolean i23 = false;
private boolean q24 = false;
private boolean a24 = false;
private boolean i24 = false;
private boolean q31 = false;
private boolean a31 = false;
private boolean i31 = false;
private boolean q32 = false;
private boolean a32 = false;
private boolean i32 = false;
private boolean q33 = false;
private boolean a33 = false;
private boolean i33 = false;
private boolean q34 = false;
private boolean a34 = false;
private boolean i34 = false;

private boolean trueIfWantedContent = false;

private Query query;
private String levelInfo;

public Test(String levelNr, boolean boss){
    if (!boss){
        query = new MultiChoice(getText("question" + levelNr), getText("answer" + levelNr));
        levelInfo = getText("info" + levelNr);

    }
    else {
        //Code for boss
    }
}


    String getText(String content) {
        setCorrectContent(content);

        String question = "";
        String s = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader fw = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("test.txt")));

            String lineOfContent = fw.readLine();
            while(lineOfContent != null) {
                switch (lineOfContent){
                    case "[Question1]": trueIfWantedContent = q11;
                        break;
                    case "[Answer1]": trueIfWantedContent = a11;
                        break;
                    case "[Info1]": trueIfWantedContent = i11;
                        break;
                    case "[Question2]": trueIfWantedContent = q12;
                        break;
                    case "[Answer2]": trueIfWantedContent = a12;
                        break;
                    case "[Info2]": trueIfWantedContent = i12;
                        break;
                    case "[Question3]": trueIfWantedContent = q13;
                        break;
                    case "[Answer3]": trueIfWantedContent = a13;
                        break;
                    case "[Info3]": trueIfWantedContent = i13;
                        break;
                    case "[Question4]": trueIfWantedContent = q14;
                        break;
                    case "[Answer4]": trueIfWantedContent = a14;
                        break;
                    case "[Info4]": trueIfWantedContent = i14;
                        break;
                    case "[Question5]": trueIfWantedContent = q21;
                        break;
                    case "[Answer5]": trueIfWantedContent = a21;
                        break;
                    case "[Info5]": trueIfWantedContent = i21;
                        break;
                    case "[Question6]": trueIfWantedContent = q22;
                        break;
                    case "[Answer6]": trueIfWantedContent = a22;
                        break;
                    case "[Info6]": trueIfWantedContent = i22;
                        break;
                    case "[Question7]": trueIfWantedContent = q23;
                        break;
                    case "[Answer7]": trueIfWantedContent = a23;
                        break;
                    case "[Info7]": trueIfWantedContent = i23;
                        break;
                    case "[Question8]": trueIfWantedContent = q24;
                        break;
                    case "[Answer8]": trueIfWantedContent = a24;
                        break;
                    case "[Info8]": trueIfWantedContent = i24;
                        break;
                    case "[Question9]": trueIfWantedContent = q31;
                        break;
                    case "[Answer9]": trueIfWantedContent = a31;
                        break;
                    case "[Info9]": trueIfWantedContent = i31;
                        break;
                    case "[Question10]": trueIfWantedContent = q32;
                        break;
                    case "[Answer10]": trueIfWantedContent = a32;
                        break;
                    case "[Info10]": trueIfWantedContent = i32;
                        break;
                    case "[Question11]": trueIfWantedContent = q33;
                        break;
                    case "[Answer11]": trueIfWantedContent = a33;
                        break;
                    case "[Info11]": trueIfWantedContent = i33;
                        break;
                    case "[Question12]": trueIfWantedContent = q34;
                        break;
                    case "[Answer12]": trueIfWantedContent = a34;
                        break;
                    case "[Info12]": trueIfWantedContent = i34;
                        break;
                }
                if (trueIfWantedContent) {
                    s = s + lineOfContent.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "");
                }
                lineOfContent = fw.readLine();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(s);
        return question;
    }



private void setCorrectContent(String content){
    switch (content){
        case "question1": q11 = true;
            break;
        case "answer1": a11 = true;
            break;
        case "info1": i11 = true;
            break;
        case "question2": q12 = true;
            break;
        case "answer2": a12 = true;
            break;
        case "info2": i12 = true;
            break;
        case "question3": q13 = true;
            break;
        case "answer3": a13 = true;
            break;
        case "info3": i13 = true;
            break;
        case "question4": q14 = true;
            break;
        case "answer4": a14 = true;
            break;
        case "info4": i14 = true;
            break;
        case "question5": q21 = true;
            break;
        case "answer5": a21 = true;
            break;
        case "info5": i21 = true;
            break;
        case "question6": q22 = true;
            break;
        case "answer6": a22 = true;
            break;
        case "info6": i22 = true;
            break;
        case "question7": q23 = true;
            break;
        case "answer7": a23 = true;
            break;
        case "info7": i23 = true;
            break;
        case "question8": q24 = true;
            break;
        case "answer8": a24 = true;
            break;
        case "info8": i24 = true;
            break;
        case "question9": q31 = true;
            break;
        case "answer9": a31 = true;
            break;
        case "info9": i31 = true;
            break;
        case "question10": q32 = true;
            break;
        case "answer10": a32 = true;
            break;
        case "info10": i32 = true;
            break;
        case "question11": q33 = true;
            break;
        case "answer11": a33 = true;
            break;
        case "info11": i33 = true;
            break;
        case "question12": q34 = true;
            break;
        case "answer12": a34 = true;
            break;
        case "info12": i34 = true;
            break;
    }
```

.txt-file:

```
[Question1]
What's 5+5? 1
[Answer1]
10 1
[Info1]
Info about addition 1
[Question2]
What's 4-2? 1
[Answer2]
2 1
[Info2]
Info about subtraction 1
[Question3]
What's 2*3? 1
[Answer3]
6 1
[Info3]
Info about multiplication 1
[Question4]
What's 8/4? 1
[Answer4]
2 1
[Info4]
Info about division 1
[Question5]
What's 5+5? 2
[Answer5]
10 2
[Info5]
Info about addition 2
[Question6]
What's 4-2? 2
[Answer6]
2 2
[Info6]
Info about subtraction 2
[Question7]
What's 2*3? 2
[Answer7]
6 2
[Info7]
Info about multiplication 2
[Question8]
What's 8/4? 2
[Answer8]
2 2
[Info8]
Info about division 2
[Question9]
What's 5+5? 3
[Answer9]
10 3
[Info9]
Info about addition 3
[Question10]
What's 4-2? 3
[Answer10]
2 3
[Info10]
Info about subtraction 3
[Question11]
What's 2*3? 3
[Answer11]
6 3
[Info11]
Info about multiplication 3
[Question12]
What's 8/4? 3
[Answer12]
2 3
[Info12]
Info about division 3
```

Comment: Instead of using 34 named variables for `q1`- `q34` and `a1` -  `a34` you could have 2 appropriately sized arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a good reason to always go back to the file to figure out the question/answer/info?

It seems more logical to me to read the file once when you start the program and preload all the data into memory.

Use a specific fitting structure for the data. My initial thought is to use a class like:

```
public class Problem {
    private int number;
    private String question;
    private String answer;
    private String info;

    public Problem(int number, String question, String answer, String info){
        this.number = number;
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = question;
        this.info = info;
    }

    //add getters
}
```

And then go through the file, reading 6 lines each time so you have all the info to construct a `Problem`. Put all those `Problem`s into a `List<Problem>` or `Map<Integer, Problem>` or another datastructure of your choice that makes it easy to find a specific `Problem`. Now you can close the file and work with the in-memory `Problem`s instead.

This should make it a lot easier to work with :)